# Python adding headers to CSV

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django but I think this is a Python question....

**How do I amend and write some headings at the top of my already uploaded CSV file?**

File uploaded

```
jack;1st street ;New York
```

What I want to append to the CSV

```
name;street;area
jack;1st street ;New York
```

This is how I read it once it uploaded:

```
 import csv
    file = upload.filepath
    file_read = csv.reader(file.read().splitlines())
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `csv.reader(file)` is enough; no need to read and split lines, leave the reading up to the `csv` module instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DictReader and DictWriter to save as a new file with headers...

```
file_read = csv.DictReader(open('/tmp/test.csv', 'rb'), 
    ['name','street','area'], delimiter=';')
file_write = csv.DictWriter(open('/tmp/test-headers.csv', 'wb'), 
    ['name','street','area'], delimiter=';')
file_write.writeheader()
file_write.writerows(file_read)
```

Or, if you just want to use the file in your script:

```
file_read = csv.DictReader(open('/tmp/test.csv', 'rb'), 
    ['name','street','area'], delimiter=';')

for row in file_read:
    print row
```

The above prints:

```
{'street': ' 1st street', 'name': 'jack', 'area': ' New York'}
{'street': ' 2nd street', 'name': 'sally', 'area': ' New York'}
```